# Bootstrap Tab break on small devices

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all I am creating a real estate website for Kerala **[Real estate website in kerala nook.in](http://nbook.in/)**.. On the home page User can search properties with an advanced property search form. There are several categories to search.

**My problem is**
On home page of this website I am add a search form with tab. But this tab break it's design and overflow out of the background on small device please help..

[image: Real estate Website in kerala nbook.in]

Answer (score 0):

try this http://openam.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/ 
in your code to make your tab responsive.